# converting KML to another format using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, kml

I am trying to convert a KML which got generated from JAK (with the default ns3 namespace) to a KML without namespace elements. Referred to XSLT related Questions and found one XSLT :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns3="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="ns3:kml">
     <xsl:copy >
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My original KML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:kml xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:ns3="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <ns3:Document>
        <ns3:name>testTrail</ns3:name>
       </ns3:Document>
</ns3:kml>
```

Result of Transformation :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns3:kml xmlns:ns3="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <Document>
            <name>testTrail</name>
    </Document>
    </kml>
```

Desired Result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
        <Document>
            <name>testTrail</name>
    </Document>
    </kml>
```

How do I make sure I include the namespace xmlns in the kml tag ?
Tried using differnt combinations in XSLT .Please help. Been trying this for a long time now.

Tried xslt suggested by @zx485 the resultant xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns0:kml xmlns:ns0="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <ns1:Document xmlns:ns1="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
        <ns2:name xmlns:ns2="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">testTrail</ns2:name>
```

I do not want the ns1 ns2 .. namespaces prefixing the tags.

Comment: I modified my answer to give a complete and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `namespace-uri()` to the `xsl:element` of your XSLT like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

This uses the namespace of the current matched node and copies `text()` nodes.

**EDIT:** I just used the above snippet. The following template was removed and everything seemed to work as required.

```
<xsl:template match="ns3:kml">
  <xsl:copy >
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>testTrail</name>
       </Document>
</kml>
```